# Python fabric cannot start squid on the remote server

Tags: python, fabric, squid

I use this command `sudo('/opt/squid/sbin/squid')`, nothing happend, but if I ran `sudo /opt/squid/sbin/squid`, it works.

What's the difference between fabric ssh and shell?

UPDATE: My OS is Amazon Linux, based on CentOS/RedHat

Comment: What is the operating system / distro of the remote server ?

Comment: @ronnix I've update my question, distro is Amazon Linux

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely something to do with the pty settings. Take a look at [this FAQ section](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/faq.html#init-scripts-don-t-work) for more insight.